# Trying to transfer Asset, but got "data item is not resolved"

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I try to send  an asset (a test image) from the mobile to the wear device. I follow the official [Guide for transfering Assets](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/assets.html) I took the  "DataLayerListenerService". The problem is, that  I get "data item is not resolved" on `DataMapItem.fromDataItem(dataItem);` "data item is not resolved".

I am really stuck here and I don't get it from the documentation. Plz help.

```
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
            for (DataEvent event : dataEvents) {
                if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED &&
                        event.getDataItem().getUri().getPath().equals("/image")) {
                    DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(dataItem);
                    Asset profileAsset = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getAsset("profileImage");
                    Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmapFromAsset(profileAsset);
                    // Do something with the bitmap
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: **ALWAYS** include the logcat in the question when you get exceptions.

Comment: I would do this, but it is not possible to compile this code.

Comment: As the answer below indicates, it's a mistake in Google's code, which sadly seems to be a trend throughout Wear documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call [`getDataItem()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataEvent.html#getDataItem%28%29) on the `DataEvent` instance.

This line:

```
    DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(dataItem);
```

should be instead:

```
    DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event.getDataItem());
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved this Error, but now I have the problem, that when I call "mGoogleApiClient.connect();" in the mobile activity it crashes.

Comment: @UhrArt Please post the call stack and any other relevant details -- preferably as another question, since it's another issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

@matiash

Ok I found the solution. According to the ADB logs in Android Studio it was missing following in the AndroidManifest.xml in the mobile app.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I'll try now to send the asset to the device.
Thank you all for pointing to the right direction.